# Highmaps downloadXLS() issue with MacOS Safari

Tags: javascript, highcharts, mime-types

I'd like to export my map data programmatically using the Highmaps downloadXLS() function.  It works as expected in Firefox and Chrome, but does not in MacOS Safari.  I get a "cannot decode raw data" error in the console.  It probably has something to do with mime-types.  Any thoughts?

I simply use myChart.downloadXLS() on a button click.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @reward72, I have tested the `downloadXLS` method in Safari v12.1.2 and it works fine. What Highcharts version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what I did, but it works just fine now. Looks like it was a false alarm. Sorry and thank you for trying!